# How to set the elements of NSMutableArray to UILabel in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am new to IOS. I have set the data into `NSMutableArray`. I want to get the `elements` of `NSMutableArray` and set it to the `UILabel` like the following.

```
self.RedValue.text = [LEDstate objectAtIndex:0];
```

But it crash for following reason:

**`2015-03-04 19:01:24.384 BLE_Running[1610:870444] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14561760'`**

**How to set the elements of NSMutableArray to UILabel in Objective-C ?**

Comment: How did you populate LEDState ? I think it contains NSNumber not NSString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you assign `NSString` object to `self.RedValue.text`

```
id objectFromArray = [LEDstate objectAtIndex:0];
self.RedValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objectFromArray];
```

**EDIT**

We need to assign `NSString` object to label, So, its better to convert the object stored in array(whatever it may be, for e.g. an integer,NSNumber etc..) to `NSString` object and then assign it to label,
We can convert `NSNumber` object to string like

```
NSNumber *objectFromArray = [LEDstate objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *stringValueOfNumber = [objectFromArray stringValue]
```

Comment: Because `stringWithFormat ` converts `id` type to `NSString` @MidhunMP

Comment: It won't convert anything. It act as a control string and shows the description of that object. what happens if that returns an array or nsdictionary, will that give desired output ? Also from the error warning it's clear that the OP have NSNumber in the array, so why can't you just use the stringValue property, instead of this hack ?

Comment: i know that simply we can type cast `id` to `NSString` like `NSString *stringValue = (NSString *) objectFromArray`; But i dont know which one is preferable

Comment: I'm not talking about typeCasting. It is also not a solution in this context. Check the below answers. I'm talking about that. In any situation your solution is not preferred. It is something like a hack, not a good solution(You can find the reasons in SO itself). And I'm not arguing with you, but it's a fact

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass integer to String, Label accepts string not integer,

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Add Bool to Array
    [mutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    // Add number to Array
    [mutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

    // Add String to Array
    [mutableArray addObject:@"String"];

    // Create a lable to Show result
    UILabel *lable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);
    lable.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:lable];


    // set lable text from Mutable array

    lable.text = [[mutableArray objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]; //Bool

                    //or
    lable.text = [[mutableArray objectAtIndex:1] stringValue]; //int

                    //or
    lable.text = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:2]; //string
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains `NSNumber` objects not `NSString` objects. You can't assign `NSNumber` to label's text property in this way. You need to convert it to string first. For that you can use the [stringValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/stringValue) property of `NSNumber` object.

```
self.RedValue.text = [[LEDstate objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
```